# uninitialized constant Yaml (NameError) using ruby2.1.2

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, yaml

I am new with ruby.
I want to use simple yml settings file
this is my code

## LaunchEC2s.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'yaml'
AWS_CON = Yaml.load_file("AWSsettings.yml") unless defined? AWS_CON

def launchEC2(count)
key_pair = ec2.key_pairs[AWS_CON['key_pair']]
    image_id
ec2 = AWS::EC2.new.regions[AWS_CON['region']]
instances = ec2.instances.create(
    :image_id => AWS_CON['image_id'],
    :instance_type => AWS_CON['instance_type'],
    :count => count,
    :security_groups => AWS_CON['security_groups'],
    :key_pair => key_pair)
end
launchEC2(2)
```

my yml file looks like

```
# AWS yml file
key_pair: xxx
region: us-west-2
image_id: ami-b5a7ea85
instance_type: t2.micro
security_groups: xxx
```

**when I run it I get**

```
./LaunchEC2s.rb:6:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Yaml (NameError)
```

I'm sorry is this question is dumb but I cant figure it up
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: try all caps on 'Yaml' so it should be 'YAML'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want to do `YAML.load_file("AWSsettings.yml")` instead of `Yaml.load_file("AWSsettings.yml")` (the difference being all caps).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Create a yml file in config/

say config/ec2_keys.yml

```
development: 
 region: us-west-2
 image_id: ami-b5a7ea85
 instance_type: t2.micro
 security_groups: xxx
```

Now you want to initialize them once for all. For that create this one line file:
config/initializers/load_ec2.rb

```
EC2 = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/ec2_keys.yml")).result)[Rails.env]
```

Now use the constants wherever required as:

```
EC2["region"]
#=> "us-west-2"
EC2["image_id"]
#=> "ami-b5a7ea85"
```

Comment: nice idea I'll try it as well :)

Comment: sure. :) In my opinion if the constant is used more than once in different files, they should always be initialized in the beginning when the application is loaded.